# Word prompts me to save my document after exporting it to a PDF

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word-2013

Even though I have not changed the contents of the document since hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, after I exported the document to PDF, I am confronted with "*Want to save your changes...?*" message when I try to exit Word 2013.

So, what is changing? And why do I need to save again?

Order of events:

1. Saving the document
2. Exporting to PDF
3. Attempting to exit Microsoft Word

   - "Want to save you changes to [document name]?"
   - WELL DUH! I WANNA SAVE! *BUT WHAT AM I SAVING*?

Comment: What version you using? Just tried it on my copy, 2013, and it didn't prompt me.

Comment: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013.

Comment: Just tried again (Also Pro Plus 2013) and still no prompt to save. Its a long shot but does track changes give you any clues?

Comment: Nope! I just did some brief searching around and it seems that _printing_ a Word document will change some of the meta-data and thus will require another save. Maybe PDFs follow the same process?

Comment: Are you using the build in export to PDF feature or using an Adobe / 3rd party add-in / extension? Mine definitely does not prompt me to resave again after using the build in export feature. How odd

Comment: I am also using the built-in function under File... Export... Create PDF/XPS.

Comment: Does it happen when you press `F12` (shortcut for save as) > Save as type: `PDF` ?

Comment: Maybe you changed some options in Word settings. Maybe you checked somewhere in the settings of Word that you want it to prompt you to save the document every time you close Word. Is this happening also when you export the file for the second time to pdf ? The first time it will prompt you to save, but when you export again (without closing word) does it again prompt you to save the document ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Word treats "export..." as "print...", so after exporting to PDF file, the metadata "last printed time" would be updated, therefore asking you to save before exit. If you don't want this prompt, maybe you could remove this metadata by right click on the file,"Properties", "Detail...", "remove properties and personal info", since that I'm using Chinese edition, the actual tab tag maybe different from I mentioned before.

[image: Detail information of a file]